# What is the unit type in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, types, plsql, unit-type, singleton-type

What is the unit type in PL/SQL? If there is no built-in type, how do I make one?

Comment: a type with only one value in it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type

Comment: There is no unit type in PL/SQL, probably because it would not be very useful. I'd be interested to know what you're trying to accomplish with a type that can't store any useful information.

Comment: The problem is I can't get how to make types in PL/SQL. For example I want to make my own realization of Boolean. Well, I'd better make another question specifically on that topic.

Comment: Note that the boolean data type exist in PL/SQL, not in Oracle SQL. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/datatypes.htm#CJACJGBG

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are trying to create your own type. In Oracle you can achieve that with the `CREATE TYPE` statement.

> Use the CREATE TYPE statement to create the specification of an object
>   type, a SQLJ object type, a named varying array (varray), a nested
>   table type, or an incomplete object type. You create object types with
>   the CREATE TYPE and the CREATE TYPE BODY statements. The CREATE TYPE
>   statement specifies the name of the object type, its attributes,
>   methods, and other properties. The CREATE TYPE BODY statement contains
>   the code for the methods that implement the type.

You can define the behavior of your own object.

[link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8001.htm)